# Table cells exactly 50% of the height and 50% of the width

Tags: html, css

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y5DZ/). The cells have different height/width depending on the content. I would like to constrain them to exactly 50% of the width and height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
tr { height: 50% }
td { width: 50% }
```

to your CSS, updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/4y5DZ/4/).